# Html/php email page/form

Tags: php, html, email

I want to use php and HTML to create a contact page so users can send me an message directly from the website to my email-account

The only problem I have is that, it doesn't send any messages to my email-inbox(no errors on page)

Here is the code:

HTML(no css style): INDEX.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>

<head>
    <title>Contact US</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">



        <div id="contact-area">
            SEND US A MESSAGE:
            <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

                <label for="City">City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP: contactengine.php

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "JhonDoe@domain.com";<-- not sure about this one
$EmailTo = "MyEmail@domain.com";
$Subject = "WebSite Message";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


?>
```

Comment: `mail()` function is irreliable. I recommend [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) + external SMTP server.

Comment: You sure the server is configured to send mail?

Comment: It's possible your server/hosting isn't set up properly to send mail.  I will typically use swiftmailer if I have trouble making the server work for me.  It is strictly php-based, and works most anywhere: [link](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Currently im using a free webhosting service called: ByetHost.com, there can be a chance that they don't allow email to be made...

Comment: If this is your code, it will fail `$EmailFrom = "JhonDoe@domain.com";<-- not sure about this one` --- I tried your form and it worked for me. Change it to `$EmailFrom = "JhonDoe@domain.com";`

Comment: the form works but if i send a message from the form, i never recieve a email....

Comment: @MKSA Are you using this on a local machine, or Live via the web?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I'm using i live through the web

Comment: @MKSA Have you checked your Spam? Cuz like I said earlier, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @MKSA and did you get rid of `<-- not sure about this one` in `$EmailFrom = "JhonDoe@domain.com";<-- not sure about this one` ?

Comment: @MKSA and this `$EmailFrom = "JhonDoe@domain.com";` actually, should be `$EmailFrom = $_POST['Email'];` since it will grab the email from your form name `<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />` and `$EmailTo = "MyEmail@domain.com";` is YOUR email address.

Comment: i will give that a try, do i have to change any settings for this kind of page on my webserver? or do i just upload the pages?

Comment: @MKSA Added note: Instead of using `validationOK`, get rid of those and use `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { die("The email <b>$email</b> you entered, is not valid."); exit; }` instead. Tthat will take care of validation.

Comment: @MKSA You will have to upload in order to update everything and reload, and using what I put above this comment instead. It will work much better ;-)

Comment: sigh.... i have done EVERYTHING you said and even started over like 3 time but still no luck....

Comment: @MKSA I just signed up for a free account there, where you have it hosted and tested your script and I did NOT receive an email, so it looks like they do not offer `mail()` functionality unless you pay for it. Problem solved, not good but solved nonetheless.

Comment: so the problem is not in the code but at the web-server? THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!! i really appreciate all your effort!

Comment: @MKSA You're welcome. Read this, it will explain it => http://byet.net/discussion/comment/1703#Comment_1703

Comment: @MKSA The only way to invoke a mailer while using a form on your site, would be to use `<form action="mailto:email@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">` that is the only way, unfortunately.